# onclick show the content of the folder clicked-on in a php page

Tags: php, ftp

Hi I have the following code of my PHP page that shows me the content of a directory in another server through FTP functions

```
<?php
$conn = ftp_connect("host") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn,"username","password");
$files = ftp_nlist($conn,"logs");
foreach($files as $value)
    {
    echo $value;
    }
ftp_close($conn);
?>
```

this directory contains sub-directories , what I want to do is for each folder in the output result! When I click on it; it shows me the content of it
and I got no clue how to get this to work
this is the link of the result generated but the code above [click me](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/test.php)
should I use onclick = excuse some PHP function or what? and how to do that?

Comment: `onclick=somePHPFunction()` will not work as onclick is a client side function call. You can call client side functions (javascript functions for example) using onclick. Just letting you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code in your loop to:

```
echo "<a href=\"test.php?dir={$value}\">{$value}</a>";
```

Replace your `ftp_nlist` function call with this:

```
if ($_GET['dir'] != null) {
    ftp_chdir($conn, "logs/{$_GET['dir']}");
}
else
    ftp_chdir($conn, "logs");
}

$files = ftp_nlist($conn,"");
```

That will cause the `$value` to be passed into your page as `$_GET['dir']`.

EDIT: Final code should look something like this:

```
<?php
$conn = ftp_connect("host") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn,"username","password");

if ($_GET['dir'] != null) {
    ftp_chdir($conn, "logs/{$_GET['dir']}");
}
else
    ftp_chdir($conn, "logs");
}

$files = ftp_nlist($conn,"");

foreach($files as $value) {
    echo "<a href=\"test.php?dir={$value}\">{$value}</a>";
}

ftp_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: the code will be in the end like this ?  
<?php  
$conn = ftp_connect("host") or die("Could not connect");  
ftp_login($conn,"username","password");  
$files = ftp_nlist($conn,"logs");  
foreach($files as $value)  
    {  
    echo "<a href=\"test.php?dir={$value}\">{$value}</a>";  
if ($_GET['dir'] != null)  
    $files = ftp_nlist($conn,"logs/{$_GET['dir']}")  
else  
    $files = ftp_nlist($conn,"logs")  
    }  
ftp_close($conn);  
?>

Comment: No, my second code snippet should replace your `ftp_nlist` function right below the `ftp_login`

Comment: ok thank you sorry for the asking how to put it right .. am a beginner

Comment: No problem =), that's what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: this is the result i got in my website [click me](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/test.php)
note that subdirectory1 contains pictures ! and in my website when i click on subdirectory1 i get nothing !

Comment: Try the code I changed in my answer.  Apparently `ftp_nlist` has problems with spaces, but I changed it to use `ftp_chdir` to change to that directory, then call `ftp_nlist` jut to list files/folders from that current directory.  I updated my second and third code snippets

Comment: oh ! this is how my webpage look now [click me](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/test.php)

Comment: I'm not sure why.  Nothing I changed should have caused that.  Can you try to re-copy and paste it again?  It looks like it's almost working.  If I go to http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/test.php?dir=subdirectory%201 (subdirectory 1), I get 3 results - but something is wrong with the code and they're not displaying properly.

Comment: but when i see the 3 images inside subdirectory2
once i click on one of them i get the content of the root directory of my website ! in staid of displaying the image !
[click me](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/test.php)

Comment: That's a little more difficult, and should maybe be a separate StackOverflow question.  You will need to call the `ftp_get` function to download the image from the FTP and then display it in the web browser.  There's an example of using ftp_get here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Comment: ok thank you i will put it in a separate SOF question
but i don't want to download anything ! i want just to display it !